# Functor from modular operads to (wheeled) properads

Tags: reference-request, operads

In [Algebra+Homotopy=Operad](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.3245.pdf) in the conclusion it says that there is a commutative square of functors

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
modular\,  operads @>>>  properads\\
@VVV @VVV\\
cyclic\, operads @>>>  operads
\end{CD}
Is there a reference for the top horizontal functor or is this just working through the definitions which I should do myself (in which case I apologize in advance for the question.)?

Comment: The four corners of the square are gadgets which have composition operations for graphs, directed acyclic graphs, trees, and rooted trees, respectively. In particular, given a directed acyclic graph you get a graph by forgetting the directions and the fact that it was acyclic. This gives the top map. Alternatively, the operations are generated by "corollas"; the left column allows you to have multiple outputs, and the top row lets you exchange outputs and inputs.